# TinyMCE - how do you use onClick instead of <a href=""> for links?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way to change the defalt behaviour of TimyMCE, so that when you insert a link, it renders something like this:

```
<span onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');"></span>
```

instead of

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" location="yes"></a>
```

Ideally, I would like this to be done by the Link button, but it could be done onSubmit.

**ADDED**:
The reason for doing this (as I know it seems like bad practice) is to be able to port to PhoneGap (using the [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) plugin), as is not intended for browser use.

Comment: In order to give you the best possible solution, could you explain why you want this unorthodox behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlooking that this really isn't a good practice, I will assume you have a valid use case for wanting to do such black magic.

But before, a few things to consider:

1. I would advise you to keep links as links while working in TinyMCE. That way, your users will be able to insert and edit them as usual. Changing them to `span` elements *inside* the editor will practically eliminate the ability to edit them without editing the full source. You should probably convert them to `span` elements *outside* the editor.
2. If you're the stubborn type and don't care about #1 or your users, you should note that the default TinyMCE 4 configuration doesn't allow `onclick` attributes, so you'll need to update [`extended_valid_elements`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3aextended_valid_elements), otherwise they will be removed during the cleanup process.
3. There is probably a better way to do what you're trying to do. As @Vic suggested, an event listener would probably be a better option.

Nevertheless, I will humor you. Below is an overview of the process with a working example.

## Overview

If you are developing with TinyMCE 3.x, you'll want to tap into the [`onSaveContent`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onSaveContent) event. If you are using 4.x, use the [`saveContent`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.SaveContent) event. In both cases, the concept is the same.

This event gets fired whenever the content of the editor is "saved". This happens automatically if TinyMCE is submitted as part of a form, but you can also use [`tinymce.triggerSave()`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3amethod.tinymce.triggerSave) to force it on all editors at once.

So, simply setup your callback function to replace all links with the evil `span` alternative. You can use pure JS or TinyMCE's built-in DOM utilities (probably only a good idea if you're already familiar with them), but for clarity (and sanity) it's much easier with jQuery.

## Working Example

TinyMCE Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/mAdaab/1

1. This example uses TinyMCE 4
2. Open your browser's console to see the output
3. After TinyMCE loads, press the `Save` button
4. The resulting HTML will appear in your console

Do with it what you wish, but remember that there probably is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is a really bad practice (as in not using anchor tags for links) wouldnt it be easier to actually give your link an id or class and attach event listener with javascript and on click prevent default behavour grab the href attribute and use your window.open?

Comment: This would still need the ability to add markup to any <a> tags in the  TinyMCE textarea before submission though?

Comment: event listeners are not any safer than inline events - this is only a "bad practice" from a design point, not a security point, so TinyMCEs security argument is moot regarding tag events in markup. I've witnessed many attacks via jQuery and many other client frameworks. Remember, it's ALL running on the client! (biggest mistake is devs making any presumptions of security on the client side - there are none - client scripts should be used for cleaning & validating input to limit server trips & making a pretty GUI, but NEVER for security).